# Why only PHP allowed in html code but other languages use CGI?

Tags: php, python, apache, server, cgi

For example, why developers of Python don't make the interpreter for using Python like PHP in HTML code?

Comment: PHP is not allowed in HTML.

Comment: The languages you can mix in with html depends on what modules your web server has installed. Modules do indeed exist for python in apache same as php.

Comment: I meant the way we use php:  "<?php ... ?>

Comment: But i never seen that anyone write python code in html file.

Comment: @AndiS you've never seen anyone write PHP in an HTML file either. Again, with the appropriate apache mods you can mix templates and programming in the same Python file like you can in a PHP file. Its just that people have largely quit doing that except in PHP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PHP was initially designed primarily as a programming language for creating web applications (the name stands for Personal Home Page). To make this easier, they tightly integrated the language into the web pages. In fact, in early versions of PHP, the code was embedded in HTML comments (similar to the way early Javascript had to be embedded). The [PHP History](http://php.net/manual/en/history.php.php) page shows examples of this (this was called PHP/FI -- PHP Forms Interpreter):

```
<!--include /text/header.html-->

<!--getenv HTTP_USER_AGENT-->
<!--ifsubstr $exec_result Mozilla-->
  Hey, you are using Netscape!<p>
<!--endif-->
```

Later on, the name PHP became the recursive acrynym PHP Hypertext Preprocessor. This indicates that it's intended to be embedded in HTML, much the way C preprocessor code is embedded in C and C++ programs.

The embedded nature makes it easy to write web pages with lots of static HTML interspersed with dynamic code. In any other language, you'd need hundreds or thousands of `print` statements, while PHP allows you to just escape out of scripting mode into raw output for all the static parts.

There's no reason other languages couldn't be embedded into HTML in similar ways. But the designers simply didn't have that as a priority, they intended them as more general purpose languages, so they didn't put this feature into them. PHP can be used as a standalone programming language (my company uses it extensively in cron jobs), it's just not its original design emphasis.